# setting opacity using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to place one div on top of another and and set the opacity of the top div to 0. On hover jquery will animate by setting opacity of top div to 1 and increasing the width and height to cover the bottom div.

Now the problem is my animate function does not get triggered. Please explain what mistakes i have done in the code. Below is a sample of my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hover demo</title>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function over(ele)
      {

          $("#"+ele).animate(function()
          {

           opacity:1,
           width:"300px",
           height:"300px",
           },2000);
      }
      </script>
  <style>
      #container{
          width:300px;
          height: 300px;
          position: relative;
          background-color: brown;
      }

      #bot{
          width:300px;
          height:300px;
          float:left;
          position: absolute;
          display: inline-block;
          background-color: teal;
      }
      #top{
       width: 100px;
       height:100px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: gold;
       opacity: 0;
       z-index:100;
      }

  </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

    <article id="container"><ul>
    <li id="bot">Maclean 
        <div id="top"  onmouseover="over(this.id);">Pinto </div>

    </li>
    </ul>  

</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make a fiddle for this...that will help us to find the problem easily

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
             $("#"+ele).animate(
              {
                   opacity:1,
                   width:"300",
                   height:"300",
               },2000);
```

REFERENCE

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Example

```
             $( "#book" ).animate({
                 opacity: 0.25,
                 left: "+=50",
                 height: "toggle"
                 }, 5000, function() {
                 // Animation complete.
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function over(ele){    
          $("#"+ele).animate({    
           opacity:1,
           width:"300px",
           height:"300px"
           },2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#"+ele).animate(function()
  {
       opacity:1,
       width:"300px",
       height:"300px", //no comma here after height
       },2000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just create an example using your code. Right now it's working.
Try to don't use functions on your html code.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7u7r/

```
$( "#top" ).hover(
  function() {
    // A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters the element.
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 1,
      width:"300px",
      height:"300px"
    }, 2000, function() {
      // Code when the animation is complete.
    });
  }, function() {
    // A function to execute when the mouse pointer leaves the element.
  }
);
```

Regards